# Sonarqube "string contains no format specifiers" .. How to pass multiple parameters in one single String?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

`logger.info("Sample Text: parameter_one={0} parameter_two={1} and parameter_three: {2}", parameter_one, parameter_two, parameter_three);`

getting "**string contains no format specifiers**".

tried same with

`logger.info(String.format("Sample Text: parameter_one={0} parameter_two={1} and parameter_three: {2}", parameter_one, parameter_two, parameter_three));`

getting "***invoke methods only conditionally***" + "***Looks like there is a confusion  with the use of java.text.MessageFormat, parameters will be simply ignored here***"

and

`logger.info(Messageformat.format("Sample Text: parameter_one={0} parameter_two={1} and parameter_three: {2}", parameter_one, parameter_two, parameter_three));`

getting "***invoke methods only conditionally***"

Comment: try to remove numbers out of brackets: {0}->{}

Answer (score 1):

**Try this -**
logger.info("Sample Text: parameter_one: %s {} parameter_two: %s {} and parameter_three: %s {}", parameter_one, parameter_two, parameter_three);

Answer (score 0):

Just use "{}" for each placeholder.  They don't take a parameter number.